# unable to add a cookie included in JSP via jsp:include

Tags: jsp, servlets, cookies, jspinclude

Cookies are not getting added to the browser when the code adding the cookie is part of a fragment of JSP (includes.jsp) included in the primary page  (main.jsp) via JSP:INCLUDE.

The code works fine when it is part of the primary page (main.jsp). However, I need to add the cookie via the fragment since that fragment is used in dozens of pages where I want the cookie to get added.

Note: The jsp:include is part of the header section of main.jsp (the fragment also adds a number of javascript and css references)

Here is the snippet:

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie ("test","test cookie");
cookie.setMaxAge(365 * 24 * 60 * 60);
cookie.setPath("/");
response.addCookie(cookie2);
```

The above works fine when it is part of the main.jsp but doesn't work when it is part of the fragment added to main.jsp via . it is almost as if the response object is being reset after the fragment is rendered.

Answer (score 6):

The [`<jsp:include>`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/syntax/2.0/syntaxref2020.html#8828) uses under the covers [`RequestDispatcher#include()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#include%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) and its [docs](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#include%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) say:

> ...
>
> The `ServletResponse` object has its path elements and parameters remain unchanged from the caller's. The included servlet cannot change the response status code or set headers; **any attempt to make a change is ignored**.
>
> ...

*(emphasis mine)*

Cookies are to be set in the response header. So it stops here. Consider the compile time variant [`<%@include%>`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/syntax/2.0/syntaxref209.html#1003408), it get literally inlined in the main JSP's source.

Comment: for more information : https://developer.jboss.org/thread/39042?_sscc=t

Answer (score 0):

Source code:

```
request.setAttribute(“res”, response);
<jsp:include page=“url” />
```

Target code:

```
HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse)request.getAttribute(“res”);

//cookie create
Cookie cookie = new Cookie(“test”, “test”);

res.addCookie(cookie);
```