# How to add a cookie using doTag method in custom tag?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, jsp-tags

I have developed a custom tag library in Java which I use in my web application.

I am not sure why but my doTag() is not setting up cookie at all. I have cleared my cache and restarted my computer as well. Here is the code:

```
public class UserVersionOfSite extends EvenSimplerTagSupport {

    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(UserVersionOfSite.class);
    private StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();



    @Override
    public void doTag() throws IOException, JspException {

                 getJspBody().invoke(sw);   //get the tag body and put it in StringWriter object

                //get request object to get cookie value
                PageContext ctx = (PageContext)getJspContext();
                HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) ctx.getRequest();
                HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) ctx.getResponse();

                    if(httpServletRequest.getParameterMap().containsKey("show_full_site"))  {

                        logger.debug("show_full_site ");





                                   if(!checkIfCookieExists(httpServletRequest)){


                                         Cookie cookie = new Cookie("SHOW_FULL_SITE",httpServletRequest.getParameter("show_full_site"));
                                         cookie.setMaxAge(86400);



                                         httpServletResponse.addCookie(cookie);

                                                //write the tag output
                                               if(!httpServletRequest.getParameter("show_full_site").equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
                                                   //write the response
                                                   getJspContext().getOut().println(sw.toString());
                                               }
                                    }else{

                                       String cookieValueString = getCookieValue(httpServletRequest.getCookies(),"SHOW_FULL_SITE","false");

                                       if(!cookieValueString.equalsIgnoreCase("true")){

                                           //write the response
                                           getJspContext().getOut().println(sw.toString());

                                       }



                                    }

                    }



    }


    @Override
    public String getResult() throws IOException {

                  return "User version of site";
    }


    public String getCookieValue(Cookie[] cookies,
                                        String cookieName,
                                        String defaultValue) {
        for(int i=0; i<cookies.length; i++) {
            Cookie cookie = cookies[i];
            if (cookieName.equals(cookie.getName()))
                return(cookie.getValue());
        }
        return(defaultValue);
    }

    public boolean checkIfCookieExists(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest){

        logger.debug("inside checkIfCookieExists()");

        boolean cookiePresent = Arrays.asList(httpServletRequest.getCookies()).contains( "SHOW_FULL_SITE" );



        return cookiePresent;
    }
}
```

Even I tried adding the code without using if else statements but still no success. Is there any thing critical I am missing?

Any ideas guys??!!! I have checked the browser's setting as well, but there is nothing there which is blocking a creation of cookie!

Answer (score 2):

I realise the horse has probably bolted by the time I'm posting this but, for the benefit of others stumbling across it, I think the problem may be related to the feature of `RequestDispatcher` highlighted in this question: [unable to add a cookie included in JSP via jsp:include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7532494/unable-to-add-a-cookie-included-in-jsp-via-jspinclude)

Answer (score 0):

your following line inside checkIfCookieExists() method is wrong:

```
Arrays.asList(httpServletRequest.getCookies()).contains( "SHOW_FULL_SITE" );
```

HttpServletRequest.getCookies() returns Cookie[]. You are wrapping it inside a List and checking for a string "SHOW_FULL_SITE" inside this.

Coming back to your question- how do you know cookie is not being set in the HTTP headers? Try using browser plugins like firebug to see the HTTP response headers coming from server. Also set the path of cookie before adding it to response e.g.

```
 Cookie cookie = new Cookie("SHOW_FULL_SITE",httpServletRequest.getParameter("show_full_site"));
 cookie.setMaxAge(86400); 
 cookie.setPath("/");
```

Comment: I am using firebug, and have checked it as well, and I cant see the cookie at all. And regarding the checkIfCookieExists method, its correct as asList() in Arrays class takes an array as parameter and returns a List class object which you could use for checking using contains.

Comment: What I meant was List will contain objects of type Cookie. But you are checking for String "SHOW_FULL_SITE" in the list. Cookie object and string object will not compare to being equal, hence, list will return false always. And did you try cookie by setting its path too?

Comment: You can also check `struts bean:cookie` tag to get an idea how to handle cookies inside a JSP tag. bean:tag is for reading cookies though.

Comment: Yes, I tried it by using setPath() but no success! It should be quite simple as that, as I can access the parameter through request object, in the same way I should be able to set cookie using response object as well.